# Running into problems with react-router-dom v6 when trying to load webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a webpage using react-three-fiber and wanted to add subpages using the latest version of react-router dom. The problem is that I can't get the main page to work. Do I have to define the content, startup  ... functions in separate pages in order to get the router to work instead of doing so in the App.js file?

My App.js:

```
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from "react"
import { Canvas, Dom, useLoader, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber"
import { TextureLoader, LinearFilter } from "three"
import lerp from "lerp"
import { Text, MultilineText } from "./components/Text"
import Plane from "./components/Plane"
import { Block, useBlock } from "./blocks"
import state from "./store"
import About from "./About"
import { Router, Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css"

export function Startup() {
  const ref = useRef()
  useFrame(() => (ref.current.material.opacity = lerp(ref.current.material.opacity, 0, 0.025)))
  return <Plane ref={ref} color="#0e0e0f" position={[0, 0, 200]} scale={[100, 100, 1]} />
}



export function Paragraph({ image, index, offset, factor, header, aspect, text, see, title }) {
  const { contentMaxWidth: w, canvasWidth, margin, mobile } = useBlock()
  const size = aspect < 1 && !mobile ? 0.65 : 0.9 //width of picture elements
  const alignRight = (canvasWidth - w * size - margin) / 2
  const pixelWidth = w * state.zoom * size
  const left = (index)
  const color = "#FFFFFF"
  return (
    <Block factor={factor} offset={offset}>
      <group center>
        <Plane map={image} args={[1, 1, 32, 32,]} shift={75} size={size} aspect={aspect} scale={[w * size, (w * size) / aspect, 1]} frustumCulled={false} />
        <Dom
          style={{ width: pixelWidth / (mobile ? 1 : 2), textAlign: left ? "left" : "right" }}
          position={[left || mobile ? (-w * size) / 2 : 0, (-w * size) / 2 / aspect - 0.4, 1]}>
          <div tabIndex={index}>{text}</div>
          <a href={see}>{title}</a>
        </Dom>
        <Text center size={w * 0.04} color={color}>
          {header}
        </Text>
      </group>
    </Block>
  )
}


export function Content() {
  const images = useLoader(
    TextureLoader,
    state.paragraphs.map(({ image }) => image)
  )
  useMemo(() => images.forEach(texture => (texture.minFilter = LinearFilter)), [images])
  const { contentMaxWidth: w, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mobile } = useBlock()
  return (
    <>
    <group rotation-z={0.025} rotation-y={0.0} rotation-x={0.05}>
      <Block factor={1} offset={-0.1}>
      </Block>
      {state.paragraphs.map((props, index) => (
        <Paragraph key={index} index={index} {...props} image={images[index]} />
      ))}
      </group>
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const scrollArea = useRef()
  const onScroll = e => (state.top.current = e.target.scrollTop)
  useEffect(() => void onScroll({ target: scrollArea.current }), [])
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas className="canvas" concurrent pixelRatio={1} orthographic camera={{ zoom: state.zoom, position: [0, 0, 500] }}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Dom center className="loading" children="Loading..." />}>
          <Content />
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
          <Startup />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      <div className="scrollArea" ref={scrollArea} onScroll={onScroll}>
        {new Array(state.sections).fill().map((_, index) => (
          <div key={index} id={"0" + index} style={{ height: `${(state.pages / state.sections) * 30}vh` }} />//site length
        ))}
        </div>
        <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is my index.js:

```
import "./styles.css"
import React from "react"; 
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route  } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
 </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
  );
```

Comment: What "main page" are you trying to access? What exactly isn't working? Are you saying that `App` isn't rendering on `"/"` at all? It's unclear what any issue is from this code.

Comment: Sorry if I stated it very poorly! I've rebuilt this website: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/12/16/scroll-refraction-and-shader-effects-in-three-js-and-react/. I wanted to add the react router so that I could add a button that links to an about page that I created myself. However, I can't get the main screen (what he built in the tutorial) to work when installing react-router-dom. So it doesn't render anything at all, but just shows a blank screen without error messages.

Comment: So what is the "main page" you are referring to? I don't see where you are rendering any routes other than `"/"` rendering `App`. So are you saying that `App` isn't rendering? Also, FYI, it's more practical to just render `App` in the `BrowserRouter` and move the `Routes` and `Route`s into `App` to render your *actual* routes.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping me! I now uploaded the entire code, hope that makes it a bit clearer. The main page I'm talking about is the App function that brings together all the parts of the image slider canvas made with react three fiber. I don't know where I am making a mistake but it seems like the router doesn't manage to render the canvas at all.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? I don't see any overt issues with the routes/routing. but perhaps an error elsewhere is interfering with rendering the component. You could try simplifying the code a bit to test what is working and what isn't. Could you also try to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thanksy that's a good idea - Will try both and post an update afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by updating my dependencies and making sure that all packages have the latest version installed. I will switch to react wouter as it is better equipped for r3f applications.